# Moment.js: Check if string is in correct format

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I was checking if the moment string is correct using a regex with a specific format string:

```
const isCorrect = isCorrectFormat('12/06/2016 20:20:20:444')
```

and the **isCorrectFormat** function:

```
const isCorrectFormat = (dateString) => {
    const regex = /[0-3][0-9][/][0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]*/
    return regex.test(dateString)
}
```

And of course the result in this case will be **false** because is not using the same format.

The problem that I want to solve now, is send the format also as parameter, but instead of using a regex, I want to use directly the [moment](https://momentjs.com) format speficifation.

```
const isCorrect = isCorrectFormat(
    '12/06/2016 20:20:20:444',
    'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'
)
```

But I don't have idea how to implement it... I found in the documentation of moment and I don't see any method to test it. Any idea?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Moment will try and parse whatever you pass it.  If you know the format then use https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: moment("not a real date").isValid(); // false

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use moment [strict parsing](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/strict-mode/) and [`isValid`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/) method.

As stated in [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs:

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired/unexpected behavior.
>
> As of version **2.3.0**, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly, *including delimeters*.

Herea working sample:

```js
const isCorrectFormat = (dateString, format) => {
    return moment(dateString, format, true).isValid()
}

const isCorrect = isCorrectFormat(
    '12/06/2016 20:20:20:444',
    'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'
)

console.log(isCorrect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You beat me to it

Comment: This it's cool, just that I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using moment:

```
var date = moment('12/06/2016 20:20:20:444', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

And then use moments validation:

```
date.isValid(); // returns true or false
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/